# How do you vertically stack matrices when vstack isn't working?

Tags: numpy

I am trying to stack a matrices of ones vertically with a matrix of data (with the dimensions 164,87). I am attempting to use the np.vstack function, but it is resulting in the same answer as when I just use np.concatenate (see image).

Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: What output shape do you expect? You might want to use `np.hstack`.

Comment: `vstack` uses `concatenate`; it just makes sure the inputs are 2d.  Use `np.stack` if you want a 3d, (2, 164,87).

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you surprised that vertically stacking arrays gives the same result as concatenating them along axis `0`? How do you think anyone can help you stack `X`  with an array of ones when you don't show how you created `X`?